# How to set a fixed size for all Images inside a ListView without hardcoding it?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms to build a ListView bound to a list of objects that have images and other properties.

**The problem:** The images are now being displayed with the same size as they did if I was using an ImageCell.

I know I can hardcode the size of the images but that isn't a real solution. Also I can not guaranty the size of the images to be the same because they are coming from different data sources.

**Question:** Is there a way to force all the images to be the same size? Like for example when using ImageCell.

Note: I am setting the HasUnevenRows="True" on purpose to make the content of each row in the ListView visible.

This is my code:

```
<StackLayout>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Restaurants}" x:Name="restaurantsListView" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{Binding Picture.Data.Url}" Aspect="AspectFit" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Distance}" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

... and this is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `AspectFill`? another option will be `HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"` the last option will be getting the device ScreenSize using a DependencyService and set the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` properties of the `Image` to fit the screen width and an proportional size of the device screen Height. Something like (CodeBehind):

```
YourCell.Image.WidthRequest = DependencyService.Get<IScreen>().GetScreenWidth * 0.1;
```

Why 0.1: because I want the image to have 10% of the Height of the device screen.

Comment: I got it working with both of your suggestions. The "%10" solves my problem perfectly. What I haven't been able to get working is the the screen size.

Comment: @EstebanVerbel More info about the dependency service:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks